# Eclipse RCP/Eclipselink: persing data not working when setting configurer.setSaveAndRestore(true)

Tags: eclipse, eclipselink, rcp

I am using Eclipse RCP and Eclipselink to create my application:
The problem is related to persisting data with eclipselink.
This is the situation :
The application is composed of the main RCP and a plugin that uses eclipselink to manage data (mysql database).
 - In the file ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor" (in the main pluion) when i set `configurer.setSaveAndRestore(false);` and then i persist data with `EM.persist(entity)`, works fine.
 but when i change `configurer.setSaveAndRestore(false)` to `true` it don't persist changes!, if i change it again to `false` it works !
Any idea about this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are seriously mixing up the UI with the persistence layer, which are two totally separate things.

The `setSaveAndRestore` from the `ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor` reads:

> Sets whether the workbench state should be saved on close and restored
>   on subsequent open.

and this has NOTHING to do with your entity manager, or your persistence layer.

The best way to convince yourself of this is to create a simple small Java app (no RCP) and try to persist stuff to the DB. You'll notice using RCP or not has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

my db plugin depends on org.eclipse.ui and org.eclipse.core.runtime to provide IContentProposal to one of my Entity class and some of ui contribution, i have removed the dependencies to UI from the db plugin and i disabled temporary content assist; so it works fine.
Thank you.